# Force specific thumbnail size using wp_get_attachment_image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've seen all kind of solutions to this issue but none of them resolved my simple problem.
As you can see on the [website](http://www.emaze.com/blog/) I'm working on the thumbnails to the right are not equal.
I need to set them to be 214x121px as the thumbnails.

I've tried using plugins such as Regenerate thumbnails (after adding new image size to functions.php) and Custom image sizes, with no success.

I think it's obvious but `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array(214, 121), false );?>` since as I understood Wordpress will bring the closest, considering proportions, image to the given size.

My Wordpress version is 3.6.

Any ideas/assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use wp_get_attachment_image_src for doing this, and here's how I do it:

If you've added your custom image size like this:

```
add_image_size( 'blog_featured_image', 214, 121, false); //Featured Image for Blog
```

Then in your template, you could call the custom image size like this:

```
<?php $imageID = get_field('featured_resource_image');
$imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'blog_featured_image' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageURL[0]; ?>" />
```

'featured_resource_image' is a custom field I create using Advanced Custom Fields plugin, but the get_field for it just returns the ID of the image selected. So I assign the image's ID to $imageID. I then get the image's object using wp_get_attachment_image_src, where I used the custom image size of 'blog_featured_image'. This returns an array with all the image's data. The first record in the array is the URL of the image, so I echo out $imageURL[0] to return the URL.

There's probably other ways to do it, possibly much better ways, but this way has always worked for me.

EDIT:
From looking at the function you are referencing, this should work:

Define your custom image size as outlined above. Then use this:

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'blog_featured_image' ); ?>
```

Just set $attachment_id to equal your image's ID however you are currently grabbing the ID.